# Artifactory query language: find dependencies of build

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

In Artifactory, I have a build `foo`, which uses dependencies produced by build `bar`.

I want to list the files of `bar` that were used as dependencies to build `foo` at job number `42`.

How do I request this in Artifactory Query Language?

So far I tried this:

```
items.find(
{
  "dependency.module.build.name":"foo",
  "dependency.module.build.number":"42"
}
)
```

which looks like it returns dependencies of build "foo" in general, but returns a lot more dependencies than what should be correct (I get over 200, when I know that `foo` only gets 10 dependencies in total, all of them from `bar`).

Additionally, I notice that I can't display build name for these dependencies for some reason:

adding `.include("artifact.module.build.name")` to my request, [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51175439/2918853), causes the response to be empty.

EDIT: for this last issue, it looks like I needed to use `.include("@build.name")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
"dependency.module.build.name":"foo",
"dependency.module.build.number":"42"
```

Will produce *all* dependencies of the build `foo`, not just these that were created by `bar`

So i'm guessing you want something that's similar to

```
"dependency.module.build.name":"foo",
"dependency.module.build.number":"42",
"artifact.module.build.name":"bar"
```

Basically asking for all artifacts that were *dependencies* of build `foo` and *artifacts* produced by build `bar`