# Artifactory AQL in jfrog rt search: include fields

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang

Related: [Artifactory aql: find builds of job with given property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51175439/artifactory-aql-find-builds-of-job-with-given-property?noredirect=1#comment89365849_51175439)

[As decribed in the blog](https://jfrog.com/blog/aql-cli-a-match-made-in-heaven/), I want to query Artifactory with this AQL, using Jfrog CLI:

```
items.find(
{
  "repo":"snapshot-local",
  "artifact.module.build.name":"foo",
  "artifact.item.@vcs.Revision":"aabbccddee123456"
}
).include("artifact.module.build.number")
```

My understanding of [the file specs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UsingFileSpecs) is that it should be along those lines:

```
{
    "files": 
    [
        {
            "aql":{
                "items.find":{
                    "repo":"snapshot-local",
                    "artifact.module.build.name":"foo",
                    "artifact.item.@vcs.Revision":"aabbccddee123456"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I am not sure how to request the `artifact.module.build.number` property. 
How can I get the same behavior as with cURL using `.include("artifact.module.build.number")` in the request ?

Answer (score 4):

Today the CLI's AQL support does not permit modifying the schema of the object returned. 
This means you can not modify the "include" and add fields from a different domain.

I would therefore (in your case) use curl (as you suggested).
Something like:

```
items.find({
                    "repo":"snapshot-local",
                    "artifact.module.build.name":"foo",
                    "artifact.item.@vcs.Revision":"aabbccddee123456"
}).include("artifact.module.build.name","artifact.module.build.number")
```